OpenAI StackOverflow deal
Any idea what will be the impact of OpenAI-Stack Overflow deal on OR Exchange? Will there be enhancement with GenAI driven content?

Thanks prof. Unfortunately unable to post there as it constantly asks for adding tags even when I added #openai, #genai

Those tags apparently did not already exist, although I'm not sure why that would be a problem. In any case, I migrated it here.
